# Data from Zipped file to Cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, zip

I have a huge number of zipped files(named by time stamp), which are essentially delimited text files when unzipped. I have to get all this data into Cassandra(one time dump).

As the number of zip files is huge, is there a way I can redirect the extracted file to Cassandra directly instead of storing it again on local before loading to Cassandra?(I'm using python for this)

Comment: You would need a way to stream the content of the zip back to delimited text, from which Python would then parse and submit a query for. Otherwise, you need to extract the whole file

Answer (score 1):

If your files are comma-delimited and match the table schema (or can be made so using any variety of command line tools), you might consider piping the unzip output to `cqlsh --execute 'COPY ks.table FROM STDIN'`